# Cannot make dynamic two column table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a table with headers and data dynamically loaded from object of two arrays. Unfortunately, these rows aren't displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/x7ur9u07/4/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Input</th>
        <th>Output</th>
      <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="inout in inoutContainer track by $index">
        <td>{{ inout.input_vector[$index] }}</td>
        <td>{{ inout.output_vector[$index] }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Foo
        </td>
        <td>
          Bar
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    window.alert('hello');
        $scope.inoutContainer = {input_vector: ["0.0","0.0"], output_vector: ["0.0","0.0"]};
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out a way to make it work -- you had a number of syntax errors that angularJS didn't understand

http://jsfiddle.net/x71jm9r8/

Basically I simplified the angularJS code

- then added the `ng-app` directive to the container div
- removed the `track by $index` part of the `ng-repeat` directive,
- and finally added the `myApp.controller()`  declaration.

Comment: "then added the ng-app directive to the container div" -it's not necessary in jsfiddle. The second bullet is the key.